# Best way to store temp data to pass from web application to desktop application using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, salesforce

I'm looking for the best practice here.

I need to store 10 variables of information, in a certain format:

```
lname: [John]
fname: [Doe]
etc...
```

using Javascript. I was thinking about using cookies.

My scenario is as follows:
The user would be in Salesforce.com and they would enter the customer's information into a record. They would then click a button get a quote. The button, using JS, would write the Salesforce fields to a temp file (cookie maybe). From there the other MS application would pick up that file and read in the values.

How would you guys do that?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: If you'll be using cookies than it may be considered "cookie theft" and probably will be described as harmful behavior by security solutions like antivirus...

Comment: I think I can answer your question, but I need clarification. I asssume the "user" would enter his data on a web page. But I am unsure what you mean by "MsApplication". Is this another web page, or is it an application running on Windows.

Comment: @HowardSchutzman - Actually it's really nether. For simplicity I put MS Application. Technically it's an Easel Application that mimics what a VB application looks like to represent our green screen with a prettier UI. It can do most of what a vb desktop app could do.

Answer (score 2):

The browser will not allow you to write files, generally speaking. For this, you'd have to use a mechanism to get out of the security sandbox, such as a signed Java applet.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are NOT a good option here. Desktop apps should not be attempting to access browser cookies; at best, it's considered "badly behaved code"; at worst, you won't be able to do it, or your app will get detected as malware. Even if it was considered OK, you'll have to write cookie-reading implementations for any browser you want to support since there is no standard for how they are locally stored.

Why not make the desktop app access the web on behalf of the user? Write SFDC quote requests to a new SFDC custom object, like Quote_Request__c or similar, and the app can query the most recent record(s) created by the user via the API.

Clipboard integration, while it sometimes seems clunky, may be a low-cost option.

If you must write to a local file of some sort, you'll need to use Flash or Java, or make the user locally save some downloaded file (like any normal browser download).

Another option would be to register your desktop app as a URL protocol handler; so, say, myquote://firstname/lastname/product/price/etc could be clicked from a web browser to launch the app and parse the "URL". May work poorly with very long/complicated data though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cookies are certainly an option in this case. Cookies are accessible via the `document` global object (e.g. `document.cookie`). It can hold a string and an expiration date.

Here is a cookie handler I wrote:

http://jsfiddle.net/zbaJz/1/

Using this handler, you can store information in a cookie, and would be able to view as well as delete it. Then, using JSON stringify, you can pass it an object.

```
var name = {
  'fname': 'John',
  'lname': 'Doe'
};

var jsonText = JSON.stringify(name);
var cookieMonster = new Ovenmitts();
cookieMonster.bakeCookie('name', jsonText);
```

Then, in order to turn the data back into an object to manipulate, you would use `JSON.parse`.

```
var cookieInfo = cookieMonster.admireCookie('name');
var revived = JSON.parse(cookieInfo);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a thread/task to the MS Application that watches for changes in the directory whee the cookie is created. When you detect a new file that meets your requirements you can act on it. You will need to use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)  for this approach.
You can also create and windows or webservice that the application listen to and can pass the data this way from the web app.